# Plot Learning Curve in Rapidminer: Send Training Set Size to Log

Tags: rapidminer

Rapidminer noob question.

I am trying to plot the learning curve for a classifier.  Ideally I want to log the classifier's cross-validated performance vs the training set size.

My approach is to send the data to the create learning curve operator and send the operators input data to a cross validation operator.  The outputs of which are then piped to a log operator.  From this point I can easily log the classifier's performance.  The problem is that I can't figure out how to get the training set size to send to the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use the operator `Extract Macro` choosing the option `number_of_examples`. Once you have the macro, you use the `Provide Macro as Log Value` operator to allow the `Log` operator to log the macro value.

Comment: Thanks!  It has been said that you can do anything in RapidMiner once you know how it works.